# List of tables not in italic

Tags: tables, table-of-contents, captions

I wrote my caption for tables in italics but i want to publish my list of tables in normal(not in italics).Is there is any solution to do it?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) so that others know how your set-up looks like. Without any code, it is very hard to come up with a solution that suits your needs.

Comment: you should never have formatting in the caption text. like section headings the font used  in the caption and in the list of tables should be specified for the whole document

Comment: Thank you for your comments. \caption[example]{example} worked for me

Answer (score 1):

Use the optional caption argument

```
%\caption[List of entry]{Document entry}

\caption[normal text]{\textit{italic text}}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I wrote my caption for tables in italics

You haven't provided any specifics as to *how* you've accomplished this "feat", but you've created the impression that at lot of visual formatting including `\itshape` and/or `\textit` directives was involved.

You also haven't told us which document class you employ, so I'll assume that it's one that's compatible with the [caption](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) package. If this assumption is valid, I strongly suggest you get rid of all caption-related visual formatting efforts and instead load the `caption` package and issue the instruction `\captionsetup{font=it}`. This will render both the caption "label" (e.g., "Table 3.4") and caption "text" in italics, but won't render the captions in the List of Tables in italics. (If you want just the caption text but not the caption labels to be rendered in italics, you should write `\captionsetup{textfont=it}`.)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article} % or some other suitable document class
\counterwithin{table}{section} % optional

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{textfont=it}

\begin{document}
\listoftables

\section{Hello}
\begin{table}[ht] \caption{Once} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{Upon} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h] \caption{A Time} \end{table}

\section{World}
\begin{table}[h!] \caption{There} \end{table}
\begin{table}[h!] \caption{Was} \end{table}

\end{document}
```